# Android programming - push program to background

Tags: android, service, background, notifications

I made a program that counts number, I managed to create a notification bar for it, if I push it on the bar, it brings back the program to the front, that part is done. But here comes the question, how can I make the program automatically goes to the background if i "transfer" it to the notification bar?

I want it to keep counting in the background and bring the results to the notification bar!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you started a service and now want to send your app to the background?

Just initiate the home action:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HOME);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(i);
```